# Create Multi-dimensional Data Mapping in R

Tags: r

If I want to represent a set of values in R that are keyed on 3 different dimensions, is there a simple/succinct way of generating this?

Say for example I have the following keys - each dimension must support having a different number of keys.  In total the example below will reference 360 values (3*30*4):

```
rating <- c('AA','AAB','C')
timeInYears <- 1:30
monthsUntilStart <- c(1,3,6,12)
```

So I want to be able to access, for example, the value with a rating of AA, 7 years from now, starting in 12 month, using something like:

```
value <- data[rating=='AA',timeInYears==7,monthsUntilStart==12]
```

To start with I'd like to be able to provide sample generated values for every combination of keys.

In reality they will be read in from a database, but to get started it would be good to provide a dummy structure from a set of dummy values, that can simply be sequentially repeated over the structure.

So say we have

```
values <- c(2.30,2.32,1.98,2.18,2.29,2.22)
```

So each (x,y,z) key maps to one of these values.

Any hints or tips on how to best to approach this much appreciated!

Thanks!

Phil.

Comment: Note that in your example, you don't provide enough values to fill your  360 values (3*30*4). I will assign random values in my response below.

Comment: Yes this is fine - thanks! in an ideal world I'd cycle the values I gave, but using random values is good enough for now.

Comment: Ok, please see requested. Also, you can also use `subset` if you wish to keep using a data frame (added an *edit* section).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an array in R for this task.

First, we will create a data frame that includes all the possibilities. As desired, we will assign values that are cycled to the length of observations:

```
rating <- c('AA','AAB','C')
timeInYears <- 1:30
monthsUntilStart <- c(1,3,6,12)

data <- expand.grid(rating=rating, timeInYears=timeInYears, monthsUntilStart=monthsUntilStart)
data$value <- c(2.30,2.32,1.98,2.18,2.29,2.22) # cycles through
```

Next, we convert to an array:

```
dataarray <- unclass(by(data[["value"]], data[c("rating", "timeInYears", "monthsUntilStart")], identity))
```

Note that integers will be converted to character strings.

```
> dimnames(dataarray)
$rating
[1] "AA"  "AAB" "C"  

$timeInYears
 [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10" "11" "12" "13" "14" "15"
[16] "16" "17" "18" "19" "20" "21" "22" "23" "24" "25" "26" "27" "28" "29" "30"

$monthsUntilStart
[1] "1"  "3"  "6"  "12"
```

You can access your desired element by index (it will return the random value that was assigned for this example).

```
> dataarray["AA", "7", "12"]
[1] 2.3
```

**Edit**

You can also just use the data frame itself, if you wish.

```
> subset(data, rating=='AA' & timeInYears==7 & monthsUntilStart==12)

    rating timeInYears monthsUntilStart value
289     AA           7               12   2.3
> subset(data, rating=='AA' & timeInYears==7 & monthsUntilStart==12, value)

    value
289   2.3
> subset(data, rating=='AA' & timeInYears==7 & monthsUntilStart==12)$value
[1] 2.3
```